# How to sort in primefaces columns?

Tags: sorting, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dynamic-columns

So, I've been trying for 3 days now... First, i've found that primefaces has a bug with the tag p:columns, as it's sortFunction asks for a property instead a method. So, i've found this solution: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042568/primefaces-datatable-custom-sort-function-with-dynamic-columns)
Nevertheless, even reaching the method, i don't know what column i'm asking to sort, as I'm not sure if its possible to pass a parameter. Anyone can help?
I'm using primefaces 5.0 here.

Here is my datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{categoryBean.categories}" var="category">
    <p:column sortBy="#{category.name}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Category"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{category.name}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:columns value="#{categoryBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="i" sortBy="#{category}" sortFunction="#{categoryBean.customOrder}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}">
            </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{category[column.property][i].sumGrade/category[column.property][i].countGrade}"></h:outputText>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

And here are my methods:

```
public MethodExpression getCustomOrder() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), 
            "#{categoryBean.customSort}", Integer.class, 
            new Class[] { Object.class, Object.class });
}


public int customSort(Object val1, Object val2) {
    System.out.println("mySort" + val1 + "/" + val2);
    return 0;
}
```

So, the object can reach the method, however, i need to know how to pass a parameter or something, so i can know which column i'm refering to.
Thank you guys.

Comment: post some code... Or check the official documentation here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSorting.jsf

Answer (score 1):

`<p:dataTable>` has an attribute `sortBy` and `sortOrder`

for example

```
<p:dataTable id="table1" var="x" value="#{myBackingBean.myEntities}" sortBy="#{x.id}" sortOrder="descending">
```

...assuming your backing bean object has a `.getId()` field.

Comment: It uses dynamic columns, I'd have to sortby `#{category[column.property][i].sumGrade/category[column.property][i].countGrade}`